# How to download instagram story without login in php

Tags: php, laravel, instagram, instagram-story

I'm going to download Instagram story and highlights without login in Laravel.
have you any idea?
tnx for helping

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Instagram-API](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API) (`composer require mgp25/Instagram-API`) if you want to build something from scratch, or you could use an existing project like:

- [instagramStoryDownloader](https://github.com/naer2/instagramStoryDownloader) is using *Instagram-API*
- [insta-story](https://github.com/xosad/insta-story) seems to do exactly what you need (without using *Instagram-API* library).

## Example (based on *Insta-story*)

Gets the story of the user you select in the form (i.e. `$_POST['username']`) and will `echo` it out.

```php
<?php
require_once 'class.instagram.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $story = new instagram_story();
    $story->getStory($_POST['username']);
}
?>
<div id="center" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 300px;">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input name="username">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi It's doesn't work now because it's the repository and the chrome extension were deleted, do you know about another simple way to download public users stories?

Comment: Seems the `Instagram-API` library is blocked by github,
someone (maybe Instagram itself) reported it ;-) 
For now I don't know of an alternative, but you may get the backup before that gets ban too:
[instagram-php](https://github.com/naer2/instagramStoryDownloader/tree/master/vendor/mgp25/instagram-php)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you know about other API for JavaScript ?

Comment: If I search in GitHub there are many results for JS, but they are mostly out-dated and none of them is like the one blocked (which allows you to download entire Instagram history server-side, and still look like it's a user viewing it).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Instagram will allow that without an account

https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

If you have found some documentation stating otherwise let me know a maybe I can suggest how to integrate that into laravel